# Printing Hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I want to know the following code why print "2/8".

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
#use warnings;
%a = ('a'=>'dfsd','b'=>'fdsfds');
print %a."\n";
```

Comment: Why are strict and warnings commented out?

Comment: @squiguy:The code is tested~

Comment: You should *always* start every program with `use strict` and `use warnings` whether it is in development, test, or production. Despite what you say your program cannot have been tested with `use strict`  in place as it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Tawnos: There are no references in that code. He is *not* printing a hash reference. Also, please do not leave Stack Overflow open to legal action by posting links to web sites full of copyright violations.

Comment: @Dave Cross:My english is not very well!!what's mean that you said?whether don't post links in Stack Overflow?But,i have seen many people post links in Stack Overflow?

Comment: @baozailove: No, I'm not saying that you shouldn't post links. I'm saying that you should post links to web sites full of copyright violations. The web server at docstore.mik.ua contains copies of books that they are not allowed to post online. Don't link to these pirate copies of books.

Comment: @squiguy: "Why are strict and warnings commented out?" Duh! To keep perl from *complaining* about stuff! :D

Comment: There is never a good reason to comment out `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, unless you [`use`](http://p3rl.org/use "perldoc -f use") another module that enables those on your behalf. ( e.g. [`Modern::Perl`](http://p3rl.org/Modern::Perl), and [`Moose`](http://p3rl.org/Moose)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are printing a hash in [scalar context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values) by concatenating it with a string '\n'

> If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns false if the hash
>   is empty. If there are any key/value pairs, it returns true; more
>   precisely, the value returned is a string consisting of the number of
>   used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by a
>   slash.

`2/8` means that of the **8** buckets allocated, **2** have been touched. Considering that you've inserted **only** 2 values, it is doing well so far :)

The value is obviously of no use, except to evaluate how well the hash-function is doing. Use `print %a;` to print its contents.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu:I want to know that whether the buckets is related whith system configure?

Comment: @baozailove The buckets and the distribution you get depend on the hash-function in use. You can read about it in detail [here](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/10/01/hashes.html). It should be *independent* of the underlying system.

Comment: Actually the `2/8` is of such little use that there has been some talk of changing it to be the same as `!!%a`.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @Dark.. you are printing a hash in scalar context.

if you really want to print a hash, then use Data::Dumper

```
use Data::Dumper;
...
...
print Dumper(%a);
```

for eg:

```
use Data::Dumper; 
my %hash = ( key1 => 'value1', key2 => 'value2' ); 
print Dumper(%hash); # okay, but not great 
print "or\n"; 
print Dumper(\%hash); # much better
```

And the output:

```
$VAR1 = 'key2'; 
$VAR2 = 'value2'; 
$VAR3 = 'key1'; 
$VAR4 = 'value1'; 
or 
$VAR1 =    { 
             'key2' => 'value2', 
             'key1' => 'value1' 
           };
```

Comment: to sarathi:Thank you very much!